# Get list to dataframe with uneven row lenghts

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset

There is a list made from many dataframes of uneven row lengths. The column names is always iterating : name, var, name.1, var.1 etc.  And sometimes there are columns with just 1 row and NA.
Q: How to match all of them together?

```
 myData<-list(name=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7"),var=c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5),     name=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),var=c(2,2,2,2,2,2),name=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),var=c(5,5,5,4,5),name=c(""),var=c(""))
```

The final outcome would look like this:

```
  name var name.1 var.1 name.2 var.2 name.3 var.3 …
1  1    5    1      2    1      5    [NA]    [NA] …
2  2    5    2      2    2      5  
3  3
.
.
```

Comment: input returns error 'Error: unexpected input in ...'

Answer (score 2):

Fixed data:

```
myData<-list(name=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7"),var=c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5),     name=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),var=c(2,2,2,2,2,2),name=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),var=c(5,5,5,4,5),name=c(""),var=c(""))
```

Working solution:

```
( maxlen <- max(lengths(myData)) )
# [1] 7
data.frame(lapply(myData, `length<-`, maxlen))
#   name var name.1 var.1 name.2 var.2 name.3 var.3
# 1    1   5      1     2      1     5             
# 2    2   5      2     2      2     5   <NA>  <NA>
# 3    3   5      3     2      3     5   <NA>  <NA>
# 4    4   5      4     2      4     4   <NA>  <NA>
# 5    5   5      5     2      5     5   <NA>  <NA>
# 6    6   5      6     2      6    NA   <NA>  <NA>
# 7    7   5      7    NA     NA    NA   <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: Thats really good approach,Thank you! But my list wont take it. Does it make a difference if it is a Large list- 16425 obj.?

Comment: Your question is not quite reproducible, so it's really hard to know for sure. It stops working well when the nesting of the list varies. Does `sapply(myData, class)` return anything other than `character`, `numeric`, `integer`, or `logical`? (Namely, any `list` or `data.frame`?)

Comment: it returns for each entry a matrix. Any good advice for transforming?

Comment: Okay, this would have been good to know in the question. What are the dimensions? `sapply(myData, dim)` should give you a 2-row `n`-column matrix giving the dimensions of all of the matrices (row 1 is num-rows, row 2 is num-columns, and each column is an element in the list). What are the min/max values for each *row* of this matrix returned from `sapply(myData,dim)`?

Comment: Very elegant solution, and thanks for correcting data from OP!!

Comment: If i apply your code:   `....[,16419] [,16420] [,16421] [,16422] [,16423] [,16424] [,16425]
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 2 rows ]`
the min/max for the first is 1-9 and NA , for the seconds it varies between 1 and 25

Comment: Luke, I don't know what to make of that. Are you expecting columns to be `cbind`ed? Or tranposed and rows `*bind`ed? In this case, I think it is very important for you to step through your own data and determine how you want matrices *of vastly different dimensions* to be simplified into a single `data.frame`. My caution to you is that you (a) do not lose information or (b) imply relationships (i.e., rows of a frame) that are not actually true. I certainly cannot tell you what is best, since I do not know the data. Because this is getting a bit more complex, this might be a new question ...

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` based solution by `stacking` list and then spreading `data.frame` using `tidyr::spread`.

```
library(tidyverse)

stack(myData) %>% mutate(ind = as.character(ind)) %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(ind != lag(ind, default="")) ) %>%
  mutate(ind = paste(ind, (grp+1) %/%2, sep="."), rn = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-grp) %>%
  spread(ind, values) %>%
  select(-rn) %>% as.data.frame()


#   name.1 name.2 name.3 name.4 var.1 var.2 var.3 var.4
# 1      1      1      1            5     2     5      
# 2      2      2      2   <NA>     5     2     5  <NA>
# 3      3      3      3   <NA>     5     2     5  <NA>
# 4      4      4      4   <NA>     5     2     4  <NA>
# 5      5      5      5   <NA>     5     2     5  <NA>
# 6      6      6      6   <NA>     5     2  <NA>  <NA>
# 7      7      7   <NA>   <NA>     5  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

**Data:** Corrected data taken from `@r2evans` answer.

```
myData<-list(name=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7"),
             var=c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5),
             name=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
             var=c(2,2,2,2,2,2),
             name=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
             var=c(5,5,5,4,5),name=c(""),var=c(""))
```